# Повторный запуск теста при падении pytest

Tags: pytest

не могу найти информацию о том есть ли в pytest возможность, запускать упавшие тесты N раз в одном прогоне. Есть ли такая возможность и если есть то как настроить запуск?

Comment: Если ваш тест упал значит что то не так, и перезапуск не решит проблему с падениями, он просто будет **иногда** проходить проверки, а ошибки которые выпадают не каждый раз - игнорировать

Answer (score 2):

[Есть хорошее решение](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-rerunfailures/): установи pytest-rerunfailures

```
$ pip install pytest-rerunfailures
```

в файле pytest.ini укажи:

```
addopts =
    --reruns=5
```

В таком случае, тест при падении будет перезапускаться максимум 5 раз.